# Evenly distribute QDate values into certain number of slots

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, grouping, qt6

I am learning Qt C++ and have a start DateTime and an end DateTime and I want to split all the dates in between (including the start and end date themseleves) into 10 slots. I don't want repetetive dates and need a logical and neat grouping, as evenly as possible. So for example if there are 30 dates to be handled, each slot will have to hold 3 dates chronologically (it can happen that there will be remainder days and the last slot(s) will then hold less dates than the rest). I want to then store this data in a QMap<int, QList>, so the int will be the slot number (1 to 10) and the QList will hold the start date and end date of each group.

Assuming my starting date is `QDateTime startDateTime(QDate(2023,6,10), QTime(0,0,0));` and my end date is `QDateTime endDateTime(QDate(2023, 6, 30), QTime(0,0,0));`, I would expect something like this as result:

```
 QMap((1, QList(QDate("2023-06-10"), QDate("2023-06-11")))(2, QList(QDate("2023-06-12"), QDate("2023-06-13")))(3, QList(QDate("2023-06-14"), QDate("2023-06-15")))(4, QList(QDate("2023-06-16"), QDate("2023-06-17")))(5, QList(QDate("2023-06-18"), QDate("2023-06-19"))), (6, QList(QDate("2023-06-20"), QDate("2023-06-21"))), (7, QList(QDate("2023-06-22"), QDate("2023-06-23"))), (8, QList(QDate("2023-06-24"), QDate("2023-06-25"))), (9, QList(QDate("2023-06-26"), QDate("2023-06-27"))), (10, QList(QDate("2023-06-28"), QDate("2023-06-30"))))
```

I don't quite understand how I can handle the cases such as when there are few days to be distributed. Also my own algorithm does not work as expected and I sometimes get repeated dates in my list. I have looked for a solution on Stack Overflow but the solutions were not quite what I am looking for (they distribute the values in a way that the rest of the slots would be filled with the same value, which is not what I want).

Here is my code (ofc it does not work as expected)

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QList>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>

QMap<int, QList<QDate>> splitDateTimeSlots(const QDateTime& startDateTime, const QDateTime& endDateTime, const QList<QDateTime>& parsedDateTimeList) {
    QMap<int, QList<QDate>> dateTimeInSlots;

    qint64 totalDays = startDateTime.date().daysTo(endDateTime.date());
    qDebug() << "Total days ->" << totalDays << "Each slot should contain" << totalDays/10.0;

    int slotsNum = 10;

    // Calculate the number of days per slot
    qint64 daysPerSlot = totalDays / slotsNum;
    qint64 remainder = totalDays % slotsNum;

    // Initialize variables for holding the start and end dates of each slot
    QDateTime slotStart = startDateTime;
    QDateTime slotEnd;

    for(int i = 0; i < slotsNum; ++i) {
        slotEnd = slotStart.addDays(daysPerSlot).addSecs(-1); // Subtract one second to make it end of the day
        qint64 daysInSlot = daysPerSlot;

        if(remainder > 0) {
            daysInSlot += 1;
            remainder--;
        }

        QDateTime slotEndAdjusted = slotEnd.addDays(1); // Move one day ahead to make it start of next day

        // Adjust slot end date if it goes beyond the specified endDateTime
        if (slotEndAdjusted > endDateTime) {
            slotEndAdjusted = endDateTime;
        }

        QList<QDate> slotDates;
        slotDates << slotStart.date() << slotEndAdjusted.date();

        // Add the start and end date of the slot to the map
        dateTimeInSlots[i+1] = slotDates;

        // Move the start date of the next slot to one day after the end date of the current slot
        slotStart = slotEndAdjusted.addDays(1);
    }

    return dateTimeInSlots;
}

int main() {
    QDateTime startDateTime(QDate(2023,6,10), QTime(0,0,0)); //selected start date and time
    QDateTime endDateTime(QDate(2023, 6, 23), QTime(0,0,0));//selected end date and time

    QList<QDateTime> parsedDateTimeList;
    parsedDateTimeList << QDateTime(QDate(2023,2,9), QTime(15,1,19)) << QDateTime(QDate(2023,4,3), QTime(14,59,8)) << QDateTime(QDate(2023,6,11), QTime(15,2,59)) << QDateTime(QDate(2023,6,29), QTime(15,1,16)) << QDateTime(QDate(2023,7,14), QTime(15,7,42));

    QMap<int, QList<QDate>> dateTimeInSlots = splitDateTimeSlots(startDateTime, endDateTime, parsedDateTimeList);

    // Output the result
    for (auto it = dateTimeInSlots.begin(); it != dateTimeInSlots.end(); ++it) {
        qDebug() << "Slot" << it.key() << ":";
        for (const auto& date : it.value()) {
            qDebug() << date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
        qDebug() << "---------------------";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help, I'm really stuck and can't come up with any ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want `QDateTime` or `QDate` ? Base on your expected output, it seems you're not concerned about the time part. But anyways, we cannot fix code you didn't provide. You should post your code as a minimal, complete and reproducible example, and then mention what you got, what you expected, etc... Basically your problem is not even related to Qt, what you really want is to get 2 date numbers et divide their difference to the number of required slots.

Comment: @Fareanor That's correct, I do not care about the time part. I can provide my code but ir does not work as expected ofc :)

Comment: This feels overkill: a simple division could dynamically give `double dateCountBySlot` = how many dates there should be in each slot. From there, the dates in a slot `i` can also be obtained dynamically, with the first being something like `startDateTime.addDays(i* dateCountBySlot)` and the last `startDateTime.addDays((i+1) * dateCountBySlot - 1)`. Does it not look better than using memory to store potentially thousands of dates? Anyway, the point I want to make: this question looks like a [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is it that you are really trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that shenanigans to make it right.

The idea is simple:

- Get the number of days (including the boundaries)
- Divide the number of days to the number of desired slots to get the slot size
- Iterate over the slots and append dates until the slot size is reached
- Distribute the remaining days into the slots (can be done on the fly)

---

##### Example

```
QMap<unsigned int, QList<QDate>> sample(const QDate & start, const QDate & end, unsigned int nb_slots)
{
    QMap<unsigned int, QList<QDate>> result; // <slot number, slot samples>
    
    unsigned int days = start.daysTo(end) + 1; // +1 to count the end day in
    unsigned int slot_size = days / nb_slots;
    unsigned int days_left = days % nb_slots;

    unsigned int day_offset = 0;
    for(unsigned int n = 1; n <= nb_slots; ++n)
    {
        result.insert(n, QList<QDate>{});
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < slot_size; ++i)
        {
            result[n].append(start.addDays(day_offset++));
        }

        // Distribute evenly remaining days (from the end)
        if(n > nb_slots - days_left)
            result[n].append(start.addDays(day_offset++));
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/z3s5P5ebq)</kbd>

For this example I chose to distribute the remaining days onto the last slots.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, thank you so much :)